# How to build a Docker image for an Arm architecture on a Mac?

Tags: macos, docker, build, raspberry-pi, pkg-config

I'm trying to figure out how to use Docker's new beta on my Mac to build an image for a different architecture. Specifically I'm trying to build for Raspberry Pi which uses an Arm processor.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is very similar to the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37281802/build-docker-image-for-arm-architecture-on-intel-machine-mac

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `GOOS`, `GOARCH` and `GOARM` environment variables before you build your application:

```
export GOOS=linux
export GOARCH=arm
export GOARM=6
go build -o bin/yourapp_arm_6
```

see: [Go environment variables](https://golang.org/doc/install/source#environment)

Depending on your Raspberry Pi version you must set the `GOARM` version to 5, 6 or 7.

Comment: Note that this won't work if the container yours is build from is not ARM compatible.